# Shader doesn't apply, what did i do wrong? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

The way i applied the shader was a basic

```
var shader : Shader;
function Start () {
transform.GetComponent(Renderer).material.shader = shader;
}
```

The shader itself is just a TSF Toon Shader from the asset Store. I just changed the properties.

```
Properties {
[MaterialToggle(_OUTL_ON)] _Outl ("Outline", Float) = 1 //0Changed
[MaterialToggle(_TEX_ON)] _DetailTex ("Enable Detail texture", Float) = 0 //1
_MainTex ("Detail", 2D) = "white" {} //2
_ToonShade ("Shade", 2D) = "white" {} //3
[MaterialToggle(_COLOR_ON)] _TintColor ("Enable Color Tint", Float) = 1 //4 //Changed
_Color ("Base Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) //5
[MaterialToggle(_VCOLOR_ON)] _VertexColor ("Enable Vertex Color", Float) = 0//6
_Brightness ("Brightness 1 = neutral", Float) = 1.0 //7
[MaterialToggle(_DS_ON)] _DS ("Enable DoubleSided", Float) = 0 //8
[Enum(UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode)] _Cull ("Cull mode", Float) = 2 //9
_OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1.0) //10 //Changed
_Outline ("Outline width", Float) = 2 //11 //Changed
[MaterialToggle(_ASYM_ON)] _Asym ("Enable Asymmetry", Float) = 0 //12
_Asymmetry ("OutlineAsymmetry", Vector) = (0.0,0.25,0.5,0.0) //13
[MaterialToggle(_TRANSP_ON)] _Trans ("Enable Transparency", Float) = 0 //14
[Enum(TRANS_OPTIONS)] _TrOp ("Transparency mode", Float) = 0 //15
_Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5 //16
}
```

However, even that basic code in a completly new Unity 5.3.5 project doesn't apply the shader properly. (sometimes it doesn't apply at all and leaves it a white unshaded color from all angles, sometimes it doesn't apply until the shader component is clicked during runtime, sometimes it doesn't apply until the object is clicked in runtime.)

Comment: having this statement in start might be a problem, try moving it somewhere else, e.g. run it by pressing a key, or wait 1 frame before changing the shader. I've never had an issue like this myself

Comment: Nope, Made it run on the first LateUpdate() using a boolean and it didn't change a thing

Comment: It's possible none of those material toggles are being applied when the shader is being changed like that and that's just how the shader looks with everything disabled. You should probably create a new material in editor and swap the materials with your script, instead of shaders.

Comment: Hey @Quinchilion mind posting that as an answer so it can get marked as accepted and up voted?